# How do I set background image to a Canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml

Wpf Canvas Background image does not display selected image from local path

XAML Code

```
  <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="485,24,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="341" Height="506" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BGImage}"/>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
```

MVVM code

```
private String _BGImage = @"‪C:/Users/sam/Desktop/photo-5.jpg";

public String BGImage
    {
        get
        {
            return this._BGImage;
        }
        set
        {
            this._BGImage = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BGImage");
        }
    }
```

Why this image not display on canvas background

Comment: The Margin is probably too large, or there is no image file at that path. Otherwise it should work this way. Have you set the `DataContext` to the object that exposes the `BGImage` property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

or you can try using a converter

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<local:StringToImageConverter x:Key="StringToImageConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

...

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="485,24,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="341" Height="506" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=BGImage, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}"/>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
```

and this is the converter

```
public class StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(string))
        {
          throw new InvalidOperationException("The value must be a string");
        }

        return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

of course you would still need to check if the string is a valid URI

Comment: This code made error like this :  Additional information: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.

Comment: please check that the your string points to the actual file.
I tried it on my end and works fine.
This is what I said in my last sentence: "You need to check the validity of the URI." preferably in the converter and return some default image if it's not valid

Comment: If we add this image to project resource and set path from resource it will display perfect If it is from local path cannot display ....

Comment: I'm at a loss to explain why.
Should work well even with web URIs.
are you sure that you're giving it the right file path?

Comment: Yes am sure and checked

Comment: Ok, one more question, did you set your Data Context appropriately?
@Clemens suggested that may be a problem.

Comment: Yes sure... If i am set path using my IP or comuter name it will display

Answer (score 6):

Your viewmodel code for `BGImage` should look something like this:

```
private ImageSource _BGImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\sam\Desktop\photo-5.jpg", UriKind.Absolute))

public ImageSource BGImage
{
    get { return _BGImage; }
    set
    {
        _BGImage= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("BGImage");
    }
}
```

Comment: is it not better to bind it directly to bitmap image ?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is code I took directly from a solution of mine with the variable names changes. I can't remember if I tried doing it with a BitmapImage or not, but I know this works for sure.

Comment: Now I got error like this  Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had you initialize the URI wrong. I'm updating my solution now.

Comment: I would rather use a converter.
the OP has a setter on the URI. If he intends to change it I believe it would  be a better choice to just keep the URI as a string in the ViewModel and use a converter for his binding

Comment: @memoryofadream Yeah, that's a good point. I suppose doing it that way is cleaner, so I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: If image from project resource it will display perfect If it is from local path cannot display image and error like  Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid....

Comment: @SamAlex The slashes in the path you're using the create the URI are backwards. It's a filepath, not a web URL. I'll update my answer.

Comment: "You can't bind an ImageSource to a string". This is not true, as WPF has built-in type conversion between these types (provided by the class ImageSourceConverter). Binding the `ImageSource` property of an ImageBrush or the `Source` property of an Image control just works out of the box.

Comment: @SeanCogan I don't think it matters much, the framework should be able to convert it to a Windows path. I can't explain it myself. Most likely he made an error in introducing the path.

Comment: @Clemens Really? I've never actually tried that before, never knew about that.

Comment: Yes really. You should perhaps give it a try.

Comment: @Clemens This is a surprise for me too. I tried it right now and it seems to work splendidly. 
Not sure why the OP is experiencing difficulties though. he's initial attempt seems to be working.

Comment: @memoryofadream I guess he just didn't set the DataContext anywhere.

Comment: @Clemens Interesting! Learn something new every day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to have BGImage as BitmapImage rather than string

```
public BitmapImage BGImage
{
    get
    {
        return new BitmapImage((new Uri(this._BGImage, UriKind.Absolute)));
    }
}
```

If you are changing image dynamically then you have to raise property changed to notify UI

Comment: You should use ImageSource or perhaps BitmapSource as property type. That would offer greater flexibility in the implementation, where you might decide to return a BitmapFrame instead of a BitmapImage. You should also avoid to create a new BitmapImage each time the property getter is called. A backing field would be a great improvement here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Clemens .. I was actually giving op an indication in what direction to proceed, hoping that fine tuning could be done after the right direction is indicated.. If I myself had to implement it, the code would nt look same really....

Comment: That's not the right attitude for StackOverflow, IMO.

Comment: oh, I thought that was the right attitude, to induce thinking process by not giving fully cooked code !